# C turning char arrays into int behaving weird

Tags: c, arrays, string, integer

I have a much longer char array that I am turning into integers, but I cannot figure out why it behaves weird in some spots.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main () 
{
    char x[60] = "08 02 22 97 38 15 00 40 00 75 04 05 07 78 52 12 50 77 91 08";
    printf("%lu\n\n", strlen(x));

    for ( int i = 0; i < strlen(x); i+=3 ) {
        char num[2];
        num[0] = (char)x[i];
        num[1] = (char)x[i+1];
        printf("%d, ", atoi(num));
    }

}
```

The Output:

```
8, 2, 22, 97, 38, 15, 0, 40, 0, 75, 4, 5, 7, 78, 52, 12, 500, 773, 916, 89,
```

Everything is great until.....500, 773, 916, 89...what is happening?

Comment: The argument to `atoi` must be a string. You didn't supply a string. A string is a sequence of characters followed by a null byte.

Comment: `num[2]` can take only 1 character as the second one will be a `'\0'`

Comment: working perfectly in my system, which version of `gcc` are you using?

Comment: when I type gcc --version I get this `Apple LLVM version 7.3.0 (clang-703.0.29)`

Comment: @sameerasy It is only Undefined Behaviour. On your system the first byte after `num[1]` is set to `0x00`.

Comment: You are using a fixed length jump **i+=3** from one element to the next. It is going to fail when numbers are bigger then two digits. This is why it fails when it reaches 500 (three digits). Try to separate numbers in the list by the space, not by the length of the jump.

Comment: @Ed, but it should never reach 500 anyway because this list happens to be perfectly spaced throughout the whole thing with two digits... How would one go about separating by space?

Comment: A regular expression, maybe.

Comment: Side question: Why did code use `"%lu"` to go with `strlen(x)`?  Was  `"%u"`, `"%ld"` or `"%zu"` considered?

Comment: @Ed "It is going to fail when numbers are bigger then two digits."--> disagree.  Even on the first iteration, `atoi(num)` is using `num`, which accesses outside `num[]`.  result :UB.

Comment: You are probably right, @chux. I only looked at the problem in a hurry.

Comment: There are gremlins using `%lu` to print a `size_t`... You should use `%zu` in this question... this is another example of that *pesky* undefined behaviour.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As you can see [atoi](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_atoi.htm) wants a C-String: a null terminated array of character.

So, this

```
    char num[2];
    num[0] = (char)x[i];
    num[1] = (char)x[i+1];
```

Have to be

```
    char num[3] = {0};
    num[0] = (char)x[i];
    num[1] = (char)x[i+1];        
    num[2] = '\0'; // this could be avoided in your specific case
```

Comment: I see what you are saying and it works, but can you tell me why it was working 9 times out of 10 and then failing on only a few numbers?

Comment: @deltaskelta As I commented it is Undefined Behavior, that means you cannot predict what happen. `num` is stack allocated and at a certain point of execution the 1st byte after `num[1]` change its value and gives you those weird output.

Comment: No, that is undefined behavior, and explaining what really happens require to dive into implementation details (compiler, processor, callstack , OS)

Comment: ahh ok, so because I didn't properly end the string....it was reading some random next byte out of memory somewhere that gave it whacky values? Is this correct?

Comment: @deltaskelta Yes, it is exactly what happened.

Answer (score 1):

The need for a proper string with its null character has been posted by many.

Just wanted to add another coding idea: compound literal. `(char[]) { x[i], x[i + 1], '\0' }` to implement that.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) {
  char x[] = "08 02 22 97 38 15 00 40 00 75 04 05 07 78 52 12 50 77 91 08";
  size_t len = strlen(x);
  printf("%zu\n\n", len);

  for (size_t i = 0; i < len; i += 3) {
    printf("%d, ", atoi((char[] ) { x[i], x[i + 1], '\0' }));
  }
}
```

Output

```
59

8, 2, 22, 97, 38, 15, 0, 40, 0, 75, 4, 5, 7, 78, 52, 12, 50, 77, 91, 8,
```

Some other fixes made too.

Answer (score 0):

```
 num[0] = (char)x[i];
 num[1] = (char)x[i+1];
 printf("%d, ", atoi(num)
```

This assumes that the number of digits in your input will always be 2(for which num should be declared as char num[3].  Do a dry run of your logic with a smaller input set, for eg:`"01 50"`

```
i=0
num[0] = *(num+0) = 0 
num[1] = *(num+1) = <space> 
num[2] = *(num + 2) = ????? Since this memory is not allocated for num
printf("%d, ", atoi("1<space>")) = 1 (atoi stops after looking at num[1] which is a non-digit character)

i = 3
num[0] = *(num+0) = 0 
num[1] = *(num + 1) =  0
num[2] = *(num + 2) = ?????
printf("%d ", atoi("00<garbage>...")) // this is UB since atoi will definitely read memory at  `(num + 2)` which is beyond the bounds of what the compiler allocated for it.
```

Try using sscanf to parse the input rather than relying on the number of digits. That would be much more cleaner and less prone to errors.

```
int main () 
{
    char x[60] = "08 02 22 97 38 15 00 40 00 75 04 05 07 78 52 12 50 77 91 08";
    const char *y = x;
    char outputBuffer[10];
    for(;sscanf(y, "%s", outputBuffer) > 0; y+=strlen(outputBuffer)) printf("%d, ", atoi(outputBuffer));
}
```

Comment: @LPs and where am I denying that?i have mentioned that in the answer and in the example. The OP wanted a why and gave the answer to the why. If you are the down voter would you please consider reading my answer again?

Comment: @LPs num[0] and num[1]=space will indeed be converted to 1 because atoi will stop processing after looking at the whitespace. The first iteration is perfectly defined behavior.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main () 
{
    char num[3]; // 3rd byte is the null character
    num[3]='\0';
    char x[60] = "08 02 22 97 38 15 00 40 00 75 04 05 07 78 52 12 50 77 91 08";
    printf("%lu\n\n", strlen(x));

    for ( int i = 0; i < strlen(x); i+=3 ) {
        strncpy ( num, x+i, 2 ); // Copies two characters starting from x+i
        // You get a null terminated string num here.
        printf("%d, ", atoi(num));
    }
printf("\n");

}
```

Comment: @LPs : Fixed that.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to your question has already been provided, i.e. that a C string is by definition a NULL terminated char array. Without room for the NULL terminator, at best the results from a string passed to a string function cannot be trusted.

I am offering this just to highlight some additional ideas on reading a `char` array into `int` array, where the NULL terminator becomes almost a non-issue.

The following method includes simple string parsing and dynamic memory usage,  where the string contents get read directly into `int` memory, bypassing any need for an intermediate string buffer, resulting in the ability to read any *[legal integer length](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s3f49ktz.aspx)* from the string, and convert directly into `int`:

see inline comments for suggestions:

```
int main(void)
{
    //leave array index blank, the compiler will size it for you
    char x[] = "08 0223 22 97 382345 15 00 40 00 75 04 05 07 78 52 12 50 77 91 08 1000";
    //    ^
    int size = sizeof(x)/sizeof(x[0]);//use sizeof macro to get number of elements in array
    char *tok = NULL;
    int i = 0;
    int count=0;
    for(i=0;i<size;i++)
    {
        if(x[i]==' ')count++;//get count to size int array
    }
    int *array = malloc((count+1)*sizeof(int));
    if(array)
    {
        i=0;//reinitialize to 0 for use here
        tok = strtok(x, " \n");
        while(tok)//test after each parse before processing
        {
            if((i>0)&&(i%6==0))printf("\n");//newlines to format
            array[i++] = atoi(tok);
            printf("%6d, ", array[i]);
            //       ^ provide spacing in output
            tok = strtok(NULL, " \n");
        }
        free(array);
    }
    return 0;
}
```